# Removing a certain character if it appears at the end of cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a massive database and looking to remove the pipe character '|' if it appears at the end of a cell.

Some of the cells don't have the | at the end and do not need editing... so cannot just delete the last character... it needs to be a |

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this data is in Column A, put this in B1 and drag down.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="|",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```

You can then paste Column B as values over Column A if you want to permanently make the change.

Edit: This variation will preserve blank cells:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="|",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the right most char is a pipe, take the left chars minus 1 if it is...

`=IF(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2))= "|",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),A2)`

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** use:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="|",MID(A1,1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)
```